# Почему коллайдер Character Controller ведет себя так странно и можно ли это исправить

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

скорее всего в том что это неправильно работает виноват я, но все же хочу разобраться в том, где я допустил ошибку?

Проблема в том что коллайдер CC в юнити ведет себя странно, то есть почему то когда его Height равен 1.7 то игрок не проходит сквозь пол и коллайдер не совпадает с капсулой:

Зеленым границы коллайдера, а красным ошибки и примечания
[image: Зеленым границы коллайдера, а красным ошибки и примечания]

А если Height = 2, то игрок левитирует над землей, но при этом коллайдер совпадает с размерами капсулы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скрипт, может он как то влияет :/

```
{
    [SerializeField] private float Speed;
    [SerializeField] private float JumpForce;

    [SerializeField] private float gravity;
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 moveVector;

    [SerializeField] private CharacterController _CC;

    private void Update()
    {
        CharacterMove();
        GamingGravity();
    }

    private void CharacterMove()
    {
        moveVector = Vector3.zero;
        moveVector.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Speed;

        if(Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, moveVector) > 1f || Vector3.Angle(Vector3.forward, moveVector) == 0)
        {
            Vector3 direct = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, moveVector, Speed, 0.0f);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direct);
        }

        moveVector.y = gravity;

        _CC.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void GamingGravity()
    {
        if (!_CC.isGrounded) gravity -= 20f * Time.deltaTime;
        else gravity = -1f;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _CC.isGrounded) gravity = JumpForce;
    }
}
```

Я конечно могу просто забить на это, но боюсь что когда я добавлю в игру модель лисы то я капец запарюсь с поиском точного размера, а во вторых возможно в будущем это приведет к каким-либо ошибкам и костыля, а я не хочу чтобы так случилось

Comment: А коллайдер поверхности точно совпадает с ней?

Comment: подозреваю что где то намудрено со скриптом контроллера, а именно откуда растет _CC.isGrounded и где идет логика проверки касания пола

Comment: Если что-то вытолкнет капсулу `CharacterController` в верх, она не упадет, она в принципе не подвержена гравитации, как объекты с `RigidBody`. Его поведение должно соответствовать геймплейным нуждам и гравитацию необходимо прописывать в ручную.

Comment: Касаемо соответствия тела коллайдера в форме капсулы и модельки капсулы, его и не должно быть. Вместо модельки капсулы в играх обычно моделька персонажа. В играх вообще соответствия между визуализацией и коллайдерами нет, коллайдеры всегда простых геометрических форм, сфера, капсула, куб.

Comment: Сразу на несколько комментов отвечу: 1) Да, коллайдер поверхности совпадает с ней 2) _CC.isGrounded встроен в компонент Character Controller по этому к нему можно обратиться из скрипта 3) В коде есть гравитация 4) Если представить вместо капсулы к примеру человека, то тогда его ноги и голова не будут входить в коллайдер, так же как и у капсулы не входит в коллайдер верхняя и нижняя часть

Comment: И добавлю что с Height 1.7(То есть когда коллайдер не совпадает с размером капсулы) работают прыжки, это доказывает что гравитация работает(С Height 2 тоже прыжки работают но капсула левитирует над поверхностью, хотя коллайдер совпадает с капсулой)

Answer (score 0):

Я решил изучить компонент **Character Controller** с ног до головы, и понял, что проблема была в пункте **Skin Width**, его надо было поставить на минимум. Если я правильно понял, он отвечает, за так скажем виртуальный коллайдер, который в свою очередь и выталкивал игрока от пола и других коллайдеров. Вот такие вот дела!